# Flash can't find Logitech 4000 webcam in Firefox but finds it in Chrome

Tags: firefox, flash, webcam

I need a webcam for online tutoring, but my old Logitech is not found in Flash using Firefox (53.02). Flash finds it in Chrome, but I prefer working in Firefox. Is there a fix? I tried changing about:config media.*.enabled to True, and the  code in Terminal. No difference.
Is there a solution in Firefox?

Comment: How is this an Ubuntu issue?  Seems like a Firefox issue. Workaround:  use Chrome ...

Comment: [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) might be helpful.